# How to clear the text in edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to clear the text in `EditText` after it has been saved in database.

**Here is my code:**

```
pictureDescription.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable textValue)
  {
    String content = textValue.toString();
    db.updatePicDes(content,lastSnapId);

  }
}
```

Comment: how can you be sure whether the user has finished typing in the entire text or has he just paused in between to maybe sip a cup of coffee?

Comment: `afterTextChanged`  is called for every character entered into the edittext. so your code will save multiple copies with one character added to the subsequent one.

Answer (score 32):

Use `editText.getText().clear()`.

Comment: This is the correct way to do this. As it allows for any place holder text to be shown.

Comment: This code saved me form multi lines of code and multiple if checks..!! Thanks..!!

Answer (score 11):

### If using Kotlin, try:

```
editText.text.clear()
```

### Extension Solution

Alternatively, you can add a small extension function to make it even simpler.

```
editText.clear()

fun EditText.clear() {
    text.clear()
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just set it to empty string. I think it should do it.

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setText("");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `EditText.setText("");`

Answer (score 1):

You better do that in FocusChangedListener if you donot want it on clicking a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
pictureDescription.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void  afterTextChanged(Editable textValue) { 
          String content = textValue.toString(); 
          db.updatePicDes(content,lastSnapId);
           pictureDescription.setText("");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String content = textValue.toString();
db.updatePicDes(content,lastSnapId);
editText.setText("");
```