# How to remove the content of a checkbox when it is unchecked in Java : Android

Tags: android, checkbox

This is the code I used for checking and unchecking a `CheckBox`.

The problem is, 
For a `CheckBox`,

- When I **Check**, I'm getting the text of that checkbox and storing that text in a String.
- Even when I **Uncheck**, the data is still present. It shows the value of a checked `CheckBox`.

What code can be inserted in the else statement in order to remove the checked data on unchecking a CheckBox.

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
  // Is the view now checked?
  boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
  // Check which checkbox was clicked
  switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.checkbox_child1:
      if (checked) {
        child1 = child1CheckBox.getText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "Child 1 : " + child1 + " Checked");
      } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Child 1 : " + child1 + " unChecked");
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "uncheck" but I assume you want to clear the child1 string? If that is the case you could just set it to `null` in the else part. You'll have to check whether it is null or not before accessing it though or you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Awesome! That's working. @schrej

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear the text in edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426443/how-to-clear-the-text-in-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
editText.getText().clear()
```